# Is there an elegant way to apply {% if .. %} to a whole load of tags in Django?

Tags: python, xml, django, django-templates

I am creating an XML document using django, and looking at the XSD schema, a lot of the tags may or may not be needed.

Like so:

```
<GenericCustomerPaymentDetails>
    <PayPalID>{{purchase.customer.ppid}}</PayPalID>
    <BankAccountNumber>{{purchase.customer.ban}}</BankAccountNumber>
    <SortCode>{{purchase.customer.sc}}</SortCode>
    <CreditCardNumber>{{purchase.customer.ccn}}</CreditCardNumber>
    <BitCoinAddress>{{purchase.customer.bitcoin}}</BitCoinAddress>
</GenericCustomerPaymentDetails>
```

Now, I know how to individually specify that a tag may or may not exist (wrap in an `if/endif` tags), but it's going to triple the size of the document, and double the amount of maintenance to do this:

```
<GenericCustomerPaymentDetails>
    {% if purchase.customer.ppid %}
    <PayPalID>{{purchase.customer.ppid}}</PayPalID>
    {% endif %}
    {% if purchase.customer.ban%}
    <BankAccountNumber>{{purchase.customer.ban}}</BankAccountNumber>
    {% endif %}
    {% if purchase.customer.sc %}
    <SortCode>{{purchase.customer.sc}}</SortCode>
    {% endif %}
    {% if purchase.customer.ccn %}
    <CreditCardNumber>{{purchase.customer.ccn}}</CreditCardNumber>
    {% endif %}
    {% if purchase.customer.bitcoin %}
    <BitCoinAddress>{{purchase.customer.bitcoin}}</BitCoinAddress>
    {% endif %}
</GenericCustomerPaymentDetails>
```

If there a more elegant way to do this? Is there a way to bulk apply an if exists to the value and the tag? (bonus points if the solution can accommodate stags [self-closing tags])

The only way I can think of doing this is make these payment methods into a list of objects on the json like so

```
purchase.customer:[
    {tag_name:"PayPalID",tag_content:"pay.me.monies@geemail.com"},
    {tag_name:"BitCointAddress",tag_content:"http://blockexplorer.com/address/1PC9aZC4hNX2rmmrt7uHTfYAS3hRbph4UN"},
]
```

And then loop over them. But that will require extra data manipulation to get into this format, and I'd rather not have to go through that effort (if looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11627542/1075247) is the way to go, if you already have data that way, though.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a custom filter that checks if the value exists and wraps it using the correct XML tag. For example:

```
def default_xml_tag(value, arg):
    if value:
        return "<{0}>{1}</{0}>".format(arg, value)
    else:
        return ""
```

and simply write

```
{{purchase.customer.ppid | default_xml_tag:"PayPalID" }}
```

in your templates.

For details on how to register your filter, refer to the (excellent) [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters).

Comment: That's more or less what I've just written! Thanks for pointing out how simple it is. The only difference I have is I'm using a [one line if statement](http://stackoverflow.com/a/394814/1075247).